# jqgrid + treegrid + subgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I wonder, is it possible to treegrid and subgrid together.
For example:

```
-----------------------------
|   foo    |  bar  |  buz   | -> this is treegrid
----------------------------- 
-   foo_1   bar_1   buz_1
--  foo_1.1 bar_1.2 buz_1.3
--  foo_1.4 bar_1.5 buz_1.6 
-   foo_2   bar_2   buz_2
--  foo_2.1 bar_2.2 buz_2.3
-- -------------------------
-- |   a  |   b   |   c    |
-- -------------------------
---    1      2       3
---    4      5       6       -> this is subgrid for "foo_2.1 bar_2.2 buz_2.3" row
---    7      8       9
   -------------------------
-   foo3    bar3    buz3
```

thanks for any help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Check out jqgrid: http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html

Comment: I have not found any suitable example. That's why i am asking. There is "Grid as Subgrid" example. I found treeGrid example [here](http://www.linkexchanger.su/2010/523.html). But i still cannot find example of treeGrid and subGrid in one grid.

Comment: I thought that "Grid as Subrid" was exactly what you needed.  I do not know of any other example either.  Even the subgrid is quite rare.Might I suggest that you are trying to put too much information into one view?  From jqgrid, maybe the "Master Detail" would be more appropriate?

Comment: Maybe you are right. I have alredy been thinking about "Master Detail" pattern. [Here](http://www.trirand.net/demo.aspx) is more demos. [Here](http://www.trirand.net/demoaspnet.aspx) are usefull examples (Hierarchy -> Sub Grid (3 nested levels); Hierarchy -> Multiple subgrids at same level). But they are uselless when you do not know how many levels needed (3 or more). That is why treeGrid is suitable. To display row attached information i can use "Master Detail", but i still want to try subGrid.

Comment: Alternatively, just do a tree view (no grid), and provide additional details in a separate space off to the right when the user clicks on a node.  I understand that it may not be ideal if you are hiding important details that used to be obtained from the grid.  A tooltip might help that.